# change id checkboxs in CGridView

Tags: php, checkbox, yii, cgridview

there are 2 columns check box in cgridViewtable and  two bootstrap widgets TbButton in view page.
I can not get value of my checkbox very good. My value in checkboxs transfer into controller but changed id of checkboxs After a period of timeand , and controller don't knew checkbox,

View:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'profile-information-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        ));

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'submit', 'type' => 'primary', 'label' => Yii::t('fa_ir', 'First validation'),));

   $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'submit', 'type' => 'primary', 'label' => Yii::t('fa_ir', 'End validation'),));



 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'profile-information-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->children(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'header' => '',
                'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->offset + $row+1', //  row is zero based
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'ProfileInformation.user.scope',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->user->scope->name)',
                'filter' => Scope::model()->options,
            ),

            array(
                'name' => 'id',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->id)',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'center',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->center)',
            ),

            array(
                'name' => 'sendCount',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->sendCount)',
                'filter' => '',
            ),
            // Use CCheckbox column with selectableRows = 2 for Select All

            array('class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'selectableRows' => 2, 'visible' => (Lookup::isUser2(Yii::app()->user->id) or Lookup::isAdmin(Yii::app()->user->id))),


            array('class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'selectableRows' => 2, 'visible' => (Lookup::isUser1(Yii::app()->user->id) or Lookup::isAdmin(Yii::app()->user->id))),


        ),
    ));

// action button  

    $this->endWidget();
```

Controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['profile-information-grid_c10']) & isset($_POST['yt0'])) {

            ////Do action1
        }
        if (isset($_POST['profile-information-grid_c12']) & isset($_POST['yt1'])) {
            ////Do action2
            }
        }
```

my problem is  in $_POST['profile-information-grid_c10'] and _POST['profile-information-grid_c12'] , before id were $_POST['profile-information-grid_c8'] and $_POST['profile-information-grid_c10'] , and now is $_POST['profile-information-grid_c12'] and $_POST['profile-information-grid_c14'].
my problem is very involved. I cannot explain very good.
I want to have a fix id.
I donto why change id of check box?
Can I assign ids for checkboxs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I assign ids for checkboxs?** Sure, you better explicitly set checkbox column id:
`'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn', 'id'=>'column1', ...` see [these docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#id-detail).
This way you firmly set it and you'll have no things like these `yt0`, `yt2`...
The same you can do for the buttons. See TButton docs.

Also you need to use double `&&`  in logical condition:
`isset($_POST['profile-information-grid_c12']) & isset($_POST['yt1'])`

Comment: @Savinkin very useful your response

Comment: @maryam, i'm glad that you got help.